# TFS command line 'Get' failing

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, tfs

I usually use the VS GUI for TFS and have never had any problem.

I am trying to get the command line working and am running TF from the root of the collection's mapped directory.

When I run `TF Get <project name> /noprompt / recursive`

I get the error message:

> Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.

I have run this but the error still exists.

When I run TF workspaces I have an entry for the computer I am on (the TFS source is on a different PC) and the collection path `http://<comp name:port>/TFS/<project>` which is correct.

Has anyone else been in this situation?  The various pages I have found talking about it seem to stop after running the `tf workspaces` command.  Has this always worked for everyone else?  Perhaps I am just using it wrong?

Comment: Which Visual studio versions do you have installed and what version ifs the TFS server you're connecting to?

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the Visual Studio mapping configuration screen and the exact location you're trying to runt he tf command from?

Comment: It looks like you were on the right path.  If I remove the full path and just use TF then it works perfectly.  Exact same command fails when TF is path qualified!

Answer (score 13):

You are getting this message because the TF get is being run outside of your workspace directory CD to the directory that contains the workspace that you need to work with first.

Comment: I am running it from the root of the mapped directory for the project I am trying to get.  Is that not right?

Comment: in the tfs source explorer window under workspaces, the workspace that you select should show the source control folder and the local folder. Need to be in the local folder before doing a tf get.

Comment: solved it - was using a full path qualification for the TF.exe, removed that and now it works!

Comment: @Stefan: Do you have two different versions of VS installed?  VS2010 and VS2012, for example, use two different cache locations.  I suspect you were specifying the full path to one, and if you do not specify the full path, you will be calling the other.

Comment: I do have both of those versions installed.  That sounds like a likely contender for the issue

Comment: normally I use the developer command prompt under the version of studio that is currently in use to prevent cross versioning issues

Answer (score 3):

The commandline isn't asking for the TFS server uri, but for the ProjectCollection uri, so you need to add some extra information:

> `{https}://{tfsserver}:{port}/tfs/{collection}`

Replace:

> `{https}` make sure you use the right protocol, http or https.
>
> `{tfsserver}`     with the hostname of your tfs server
>
> `{port}`      with the port number (default: `8080` or `443`)
>
> `{collection}` with the project collection name (installation default: `DefaultCollection`)

The ProjectCollection isn't the same thing as the project, so make sure you're entering the correct values. Easiest place to find the collection name is to open Visual Studio and then the Source Control Explorer. The Uri for the project collection should be the root node. It might be that you're entering the Project name, instead of the ProjectCollection name.

If you're in a folder mapped to TFS, then `tf get` should figure the CollectionUri by itself.

When you have Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 or 2013 installed side-by-side, make sure you're using the Developer Command Prompt from the correct version of Visual Studio. With the advent of Local Workspaces, the 2010 commandline may not be able to find your mappings, where the 2012 or 2013 commandline will.

Comment: I reformatted your questoin so that it actually shows the right uri you were trying. It seems you were supplying a project name, where the question originally hid that due to the fact that it tried to parse it as if it were HTML.

Comment: Well now I am stumped, I looked through what you wrote here and then as I was retesting I removed my call to TF which has the full path and simply used TF in case it worked and made the line shorter.  Exactly the same command works with TF that does not work with the path qualified version!!!?!?!??!

Comment: I suspect it's the visual studio version that's at play here... Which exact path were you using?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\TF.EXE"

Comment: Can you post the output of: `tf workspace /format:detailed /collection:http://server:port/tfs/collectionname`?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by running tf using the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" (also known as the Developer Command Prompt) instead of running the default command prompt that comes with the operating system.

You can find it in Windows 7 under "Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio -> Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Studio Command Prompt".

You may find more documentation, including instructions for other versions of Windows, by visiting [Microsoft's Visual Studio Command Prompt MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed with:

```
tf workspaces /collection:http://example:8080

tf workfold

tf get /r .
```